# I have problem with VS Code with some functions

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a problem with VS Code, when I run this code `(0, 4, 9) < (0, 7,  30)` it doesn't show me the result if it's true or false even if I make it wrong, and also it doesn't show me the result when I use `.items()` function, I need to use `print()` before it so it gives me back an answer, the same with `sorted()` function. Can anyone help me?

Comment: The VS Code console is not a read-eval-print loop. It just executes, it doesn't print the result by itself.

Answer (score 0):

You must use print() in order for your program to display anything. It has nothing to do with VS Code.

Comment: So is there any text editor simple and has not this problem? I tried Sublime text and it was the same thing

Comment: @Last_Fox Unfortunately not. In order to display anything in the python terminal, you MUST use print().